# Code Uncrackable!

Tags: cipher

You can't crack it. There's a solution, definitely. It's pretty long.

0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200057 0005200056 0005200056 0005200056

A little code to crack for if you've got nothing to do. Enjoy!

Note if you cannot solve it;

> It's a multi-part process. It's been encrypted a few times. At first it's trivial and it slowly gets harder. Once you're at the last step it'll probably seem meaningless. There's no way to tell if you've found the last step or not.

Comment: The message is short compared to the code :P

Comment: Well there *is* a way to tell, but only if you understand how the last step works :D

Comment: After the first step in Victor's answer, you appear to get a short unclued cipher that is not Caesar or something else simple. 
 
Decoding a cipher like this is very boring unless it has either a very clear direction to start working, or at least a full paragraph of ciphertext, preferably more. I do not want to spend an hour throwing random crap at your puzzle and checking whether the result is English.

Comment: If "you can't crack it" and "there's no way to tell", then surely this is off-topic?

Comment: @rand That was specifying how hard it is. "There's a solution"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Continuing with Victor's excellent analysis:

**First step:**

> Replace 0005200056 with **0** and 0005200057 with **1**

**Second step:**

> Group octets of zeros and ones from the first step to form ASCII characters. The result is:
>
>  **TFIL E WCAT HOLN UQG/VCDL HHB SCFH JRHM IDZX V YDT DFH**

**Third step:**

> Interpret the results of the second step as Morse code, where:
>  - letters formed with only straight lines are dots (AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZ)
>  - letters formed with curves are dashes (BCDGJOPQRSU)
>  - and the slash is a space
>
>  The solution is:  **HELLO PUZZLERD**

I assume the D at the end is a smiley with no eyes.

Comment: Include the first 2 steps and I can accept.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer. I am working on it:

**First step:**

> Replace `0005200057` as 1 and `0005200056` as 0.

**Second step:**

> Group octets of zeros and ones from the first step to form ASCII characters. This is the result:
>  
>  **TFIL E WCAT HOLN UQG/VCDL HHB SCFH JRHM IDZX V YDT DFH**

**Third step:**

> Interpreting that as morse code, where consonants are dashes and vowels are dots, and the slash is a space, produces this:
>  
>  **FTFLD HSHHBESS**

A few thoughts:

1. It is not a Caesar cypher. Could be a Vigenere or something more complicated.
2. It is pretty clear that the encryption works on the A-Z range, at least in this stage. Or maybe this is a red-herring?
3. It is somewhat hard to write intelligible long sentences in English using no words with more than 4 letters (result of second step), so this may indicate that the way that the words are distributed is not the way presented in the plain-text message. The third step procedure from that produces something that resembles letters, but I can't be sure if I did it this step correctly.

Comment: Good Job so far, you've passed the first 2 steps :D

Comment: Victor could you do me a favor and @ notify me when you update it? I wanna see how it comes along :D

Comment: @victor, block lengths suggest morse maybe?

Comment: @AE Yes, after your smashing my head in your question with circles and squares, that is what I though very early in this puzzle. But still did not put much effort to break it because at this moment there is a program running for 16 hours and counting trying to scramble letters looking for the words "EWOKS". When it finishes, I might go back for this one. :)

Comment: @Victor, excellent. Have you seen the latest clues for that puzzle?

Comment: @AE Did not had saw the new clue 3. It means that my code probably will not find anything useful.

Comment: @warspyking Edited, but still unsolved. Could you tell me what do you think about it?

Comment: @Victor I think you're really close. The 3rd step, is almost done correctly. The 3 steps you have are correct in the type of decoding you're doing, but the 3rd step is producing incorrect results (did I give away too much? :O) now it's your job to find where you made your mistake on that step.